# Subtract not working with datetime

Tags: c#

I am trying to subtract to actual time some calculated seconds doing this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime();
start = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(stringTime));
```

It says that the parameter is not a "TimeSpan", but DateTime should be valid too... It must accept these two kind of parameters.

I am working with Framework 2.0 with Windows Forms on VS 2012.

Update: Found the error; substract returns the timespan.

```
start = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(stringTime).Subtract(DateTime.Now));
```

is working.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do '31 January 2016 subtract 1 January 2016', what *date* do you expect to get from this? It doesn't make sense, the result is 30 days, not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing a DateTime type parameter to the Subtract() method, the return type is a TimeSpan. If you pass a TimeSpan type, the return is a DateTime.

Therefore, both types are accepted as parameters, you just need to make sure you have the correct return type.

Take a look at DateTime.cs http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1057

```
public TimeSpan Subtract(DateTime value) {
        return new TimeSpan(InternalTicks - value.InternalTicks);
    }

public DateTime Subtract(TimeSpan value) {
    long ticks = InternalTicks;            
    long valueTicks = value._ticks;
    if (ticks - MinTicks < valueTicks || ticks - MaxTicks > valueTicks) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_DateArithmetic"));
    }
    return new DateTime((UInt64)(ticks - valueTicks) | InternalKind);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

1. Subtract a `TimeSpan`, yielding a `DateTime`, or
2. Subtract a `DateTime`, yielding a `TimeSpan`.

You are trying to subtract a `DateTime`, yielding a `DateTime`.  There is no such method.

Comment: Nice logic: you can, say, subtract an hour (TimeSpan) from Today and get another `DateTime`; or subtract, say, yesterday from Today and get one day `TimeSpan`; +1